# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I have this piece of code:

```
       void remove(){
            boolean allowRemove = false;
            violations.each{
                if(it.selected) allowRemove = true;
            }
            if(!allowRemove) throw new Exception("No item selected!");
            if(allowRemove){
                def templist = violations;
                templist.each{ if(it.selected) templist.remove(it) }
                violations = templist;
                tableHandler.reload();
            }
        }
```

Everytime this code is executed, my application throws an error: **`java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`**. I found an answer on how to resolve this in **Java** using **`Iterator`**. But I don't know how to code it in **`Groovy`**. Any idea?

Comment: Update the question with stacktrace.

Comment: Groovy 1.5 is over 8 years old... Please upgrade if you can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't that just do

```
violations = violations.findAll { !it.selected }
```

Answer (score 3):

use `templist.removeAll{it.selected}`

EDIT: This works as of Groovy 1.7.4:

```
class Test {

static void main(String[] args) {
    def c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    c.removeAll { it % 2 == 0 }
    println c
}
```

}

Comment: Error : groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.removeAll()

Comment: what version of groovy are you using?

Comment: The version of Groovy that Im using is 1.5.

Comment: can you upgrade? removeAll was introduced in 1.7.4